# Overriding buffer-read-only in a region

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want most of a buffer to be read-only, except for one small region (part of a line).

I first tried something like

```
(setq buffer-read-only t)
(let ((inhibit-read-only t))
  (add-text-properties start end '(read-only nil)))
```

but apparently [`buffer-read-only`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Read-Only-Buffers.html) takes precedence over the [`read-only` property](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties).

I now have `buffer-read-only` set to `nil`, and set the `read-only` property to `t` on everything *except* the editable region.  (Or `read-only nil` is regarded as a no-op.)

Is there a better way?

EDIT:

A more detailed description of my use case is that I want my buffer to display the output of an asynchronous process.  The output is mostly for read-only viewing.  However, a small part of a line is editable.  This part will become input to the process if it is run again.

Comment: take a look at how it is done in modes which implement form filling, e.g., customize and eww

Comment: Consider also the alternative to write an edit function. A usual key-binding for this funciton would be C-c C-c. It copies the junk to be edited to a new edit-buffer. Then it switches to this buffer. You can give this buffer your own major-mode. Bind C-c C-' to a function that transfers the edited text back to the read-only buffer replacing the old junk and kills the edit-buffer. This can be done within `inhibit-read-only` with the original buffer current. Many variations within this strategy are possible. `org-babel` works in a similar way.

Comment: @sds AFAIK form filling works with widges. I suppose that this is only the right way if the OP actually wants to achieve an effect like form filling. That means if he actually wants to input data fields and to retrieve the content of these data fields.

Comment: Edit: Added my particular use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no simple way to do what you need in Emacs 24 and earlier.  I agree with your solution to mark everything with the `read-only` property except the parts that you want to be editable.

Emacs 25 will have the `inhibit-read-only` property, which does exactly what you want.  It was implemented by larsi on 16 November, and is used by eww.